# MAX worker thread in SQL server 2012/14/16

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, cpu

I was just browsing the system health extended event to come across an event with diagnostic result for query processing showing status for worker threads:

1. Why max worker threads showing 2994 when I have 80 logical processors which as per msdn calculation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-worker-threads-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2016) `512 + ((logical CPU's - 4) * 16)` does not looks correct. However per the latest link [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bobsql/2019/02/10/sql-server-worker-thread-default-calculation/) makes sense for logical processors greater than 64 where calculation for 16 changes to 32. But that link says starting SQL 2017, however the number 2994 I am getting is for SQL2012, 14 16 where no of logical processors is 80. Am I missing something here?

max worker setting within sp_configure is set to '0'

2. Coming back to that system health event status shows WARNING for below no:

> maxWorkers="2944" workersCreated="456" workersIdle="314"
>   tasksCompletedWithinInterval="1021881" pendingTasks="1"

Should I be checking something else or can this be ignored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. why max worker threads showing 2994 when i have 80 logical processors […]

It seems there is a documentation error when the item was copied over from MSDN to Docs. What you see in Dorr's post is correct and is applicable back to 2012 SP4 + latest CUs. <s>I'll make the required documentation changes.</s> The documentation has been updated.

> 2. Coming back to that system health event status shows WARNING for below no […]

The reason you have a warning is because you have `pendingTasks="1"`. This could indicate an issue with a scheduler and should be investigated.

> I see pending task count varying sometimes 2, 4 , 8 or even higher.

In the same Docs article that you linked, there is a query that can be used to track tasks and their status. It'd be interesting to see if it's only tasks on a specific scheduler, only login tasks, etc.

```
SELECT  s.session_id, r.command, r.status,  
   r.wait_type, r.scheduler_id, w.worker_address,  
   w.is_preemptive, w.state, t.task_state,  
   t.session_id, t.exec_context_id, t.request_id  
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s  
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests AS r  
   ON s.session_id = r.session_id  
INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_tasks AS t  
   ON r.task_address = t.task_address  
INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_workers AS w  
   ON t.worker_address = w.worker_address  
WHERE t.task_state = N'PENDING'
```

Comment: Thanks Sean. I see pending task count varying sometimes 2, 4 , 8 or even higher. Can you guide me a link what needs to be check or if you can expand the answer as i am not sure when you say issue with scheduler. thanks again